# Cannot change theme color in bootstrap-vue

Tags: sass, vuejs2, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to change `Bootstrap-vue` **theme colors** , primary , success , danger ...

I have read document but still can't do that

this is **theme.scss**

```
$body-bg: red;
$body-color: #111;

$theme-colors: (
  "primary": red,
  "danger": #caaf12
);

$primary:red;

@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

@import '../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```

and I have imported this file in my main.scss like this

```
@import url('./theme.scss');
body{
...
 }
```

But still primary color does not change

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Did you tried [this one](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues?q=is%3Aissue+override+colors)? What is not working exactly? Could you be more precise here please?

Comment: I mean theme color does not change , primary , success and ....

Comment: What do you see in your devtools if you inspect it (`elements` tab)? Is it imported but not over-written, not imported at all?

Comment: I can see all assets/scss files in resources tab in devtools

Comment: What about the `elements` tab with a selection of the given element that you want to change the color?

Comment: i think bootstrap styles is not over-written

Answer (score 0):

I found answer .

I have to add theme.scss in nuxt-config like this
css:['./assets/theme.scss']

also ichanged import address like this

```
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

@import 'node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```